# BASH : Connection to an account

Tags: bash, curl, cookies

I'm a beginner in bash. I would like to code a script to log into an account to reach some specific pages and then collect some data.

Up to now, I'm confronted with logging issue. I used developer tools of Chrome to collect "curl URL" (headers + data). When I lauch the script, everything is ok, no error, but I get a 401 html file (*unauthorized*) ... Of course, login and psw are correct because of the paste ...

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept:   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" \
--cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
--data "username=TEST&password=TEST&grant_type=password&continue=https"%"3A"%"2F"%"2Faccount.shodan.io"%"2F"%"3Flanguage"%"3Den"%"26language"%"3Den&login_submit=Log+in" \
--location "https://account.shodan.io/login" >./tmp.html
```

When it will be fixed, how I will surf into the website using cookies?

Comment: well, what kind of auth system is this page using? if it's http basic, then putting the u/p in the query string won't help. if it's a form-based POST login, then again the query string is pointless...

Comment: Page source gives : <form action='/login' method='post' class='well' id='login-form'>

Comment: then you need to tell curl that it's a POST request.. it's probably doing a GET.

Comment: I added -X POST after curl. I get 401 error again.

Comment: and make sure that you're using the correct user/pass field names, etc... you basically have to replicate EXACTLY what your browser would send if you were using the login page normally.

Comment: Here what curl URL gives : http://pastebin.com/cCibiyH7

So I paste all this ? What about --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar ?

Comment: Here my new code  : http://pastebin.com/hR09UCEh

Now, I get a 302 error : "302 Found
The resource was found at /; you should be redirected automatically. "

Comment: This is off-topic, but just want to make sure you know that shodan has a REST API that you can use https://developer.shodan.io/api

Comment: Yup, I know it, and it's quite easier but ...
i) I don't want to pay for now (because I always use filter so you need query credit)
ii) I would like to improve my skills in Bash ;)

Comment: 302 isn't an error, it's a redirect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 just follow the redirect with another curl request (and use the cookies you got from the first request)

Comment: As it happens, it was my second question : how do I do that ?

Comment: The response from the first request will provide you with a new location, submit a 2nd request that is identical to the first with that location

Comment: "The resource was found at /" so it's the root of the website : https://www.shodan.io ?

Comment: Here what I get for the 2 html page : http://pastebin.com/ngFwb7Aj

Something weird for the second one .. what's wrong with my code ? Thanks.

Comment: Just as a general comment, you do *not* want to do this with Bash for anything more complex than a throw-away command. If you are actually testing a web site you *need* to use a real language.

Comment: Bash is clearly enough for what I want to do (getting text from html pages, and parsing  - sed is excellent for that). It's way too long and complicated with C for instance (I'm also a beginner in it, lazy to learn sockets etc. for now). I just need time to learn syntax and commands properly ...

Comment: sed is not a universal html parser. sed has no idea what html is, and html+regexes is always a bad idea. if you want to parse arbitrary (and potentially malformed/bad html), then use a DOM parser.

Comment: I didn't not say I want to save complete HTML pages. I just want to get IP and other data but Shodan forbid filters search query to non member, that's why I need to connect first ...
And "parse" is not really the right word I wanted to use 

That's said, I'm still in trouble (see 4 messages above)